# Slow insert into but fast select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

A select query with join returns results in less than 1 sec(returns 1000 rows: 600 ms) but insert into temp table or physical table takes 15-16 seconds.

- tested io performance : a select or insert into without any joins takes sub-second to write 1000 rows.
- tried trace flag 1118
- tried adding clustered index on the temp table and do insert into with tablock and maxdop hint.

None of these improved performance.

Thanks for all your comments. 6000 to 20000 rows that need to be inserted every 5 seconds from Kafka...

- I get the data from kafka into sql server using table type variable
- Pass it as a parameter to stored procedure
- Load this data joining with other tables into a temporary table #table
- I use the #table to merge the data into application table

---

Found a workaround that helps me achieve the target turnaround time but dont exactly know the reason for the behaviour. As I mentioned in the problem statement, the bottleneck was writing the resultset of the select statement that joins the table variable with various other tables to the temp table. 
I put this into a stored prod and returned the execution of the stored proc to a temp table. Now the insert takes less than 1 sec

---

```
SELECT  
   i.Id AS IId, 
   df.Id AS dfid,
   MAX(CASE
                 WHEN lp.Value IS NULL and f.pnp = 1 THEN 0
          WHEN lp.Value = 0 and f.tzan = 1 and f.pnp = 0 THEN NULL                                          
          ELSE lp.Value                                          
   END) 'FV',   
   MAX(lp.TS),
   MAX(lp.Eid),
   MAX(0+lp.IsDelayedStream)
   FROM         
     f1 f WITH (NOLOCK)  
     INNER JOIN ft1 ft WITH (NOLOCK)  ON f.FeedTypeId = ft.Id         
     INNER JOIN FeedDataField fdf WITH (NOLOCK)        
      ON fdf.FeedId = f.Id        
     INNER JOIN df1 df WITH (NOLOCK)     
      ON fdf.dfId = df.Id        
     INNER JOIN ds1 ds  WITH (NOLOCK)    
      ON df.dsid = ds.Id        
     INNER JOIN dp1 dp  WITH (NOLOCK)  
      ON ds.dpId = dp.Id  
     INNER JOIN dc1 dc WITH (NOLOCK)  
      ON dc.dcId = ds.dcId      
     INNER JOIN i1 i  WITH (NOLOCK)  
      ON f.iId = I.Id 
     INNER JOIN id1 id WITH (NOLOCK)  
      ON id.iId = i.Id
     INNER JOIN IdentifierType it WITH (NOLOCK)  
      ON id.ItId = it.Id    
     INNER JOIN ivw_Tdf tdf WITH(NOEXPAND)  
      ON tdf.iId = i.Id 
     INNER JOIN z.dbo.[tlp] lp
      ON lp.Ticker = id.Name AND lp.Field = df.SourceName AND 
      lp.Contributor = dc.Name AND lp.YellowKey = tdf.TextValue
      WHERE         
        ft.Name in ('X', 'Y') AND f.SA = 1        
AND dp.Name = 'B' AND (i.Inactive IS NULL OR i.Inactive = 0)        
AND it.Name = 'T' AND id.ValidTo = @InfinityDate         
AND tdf.SourceName = 'MSD'        
AND tdf.ValidTo = @Infinity
GROUP BY i.Id, df.Id
OPTION(MAXDOP 4, OPTIMIZE FOR (@Infinity = '9999-12-31 23:59:59', 
@InfinityDate = '9999-12-31))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When asking an SQL question, please ensure you add the tag for the DBMS you're using.  I suspect it is MS SQL Server, but we shouldn't need to guess.

Comment: It is possible that you are seeing the *first* row return in less than a second.  The `select into` doesn't complete until the *last* row returns.

Comment: How many rows are being inserted?

Comment: Indexes can make selects faster and inserts slower.  What if you remove all indexes from the insert into table?

Comment: Please remove NOLOCK.  With that in place, you can get badness like phantom inserts, no-repeatable reads, and dirty reads.  Also, are all the join predicates on indexed columns?

Comment: Found a workaround that helps me achieve the target turnaround time but dont exactly know the reason for the behaviour. As I mentioned in the problem statement, the bottleneck was writing the resultset of the select statement that joins the table variable with various other tables to the temp table. 
I put this into a stored prod and returned the execution of the stored proc to a temp table. Now the insert takes less than 1 sec